# Add header to graphql response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm building a graphql server with Spring and graphql-spring-boot-starter. To solve a very specific issue, I'd like to add a HTTP header to the graphql HTTP response.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

You can add the add the headers in ResponseEntity.

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> callGraphQLService(@RequestBody String query) {

        ExecutionInput input = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query(query)
                .build();
        ExecutionResult result = graphService.getGraphQL().execute(input);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Response-Code", "ABCD");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```